# Tile blocks for Joomla articles

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want to display some articles in block form with title and introtext in picture. I used Articles - Newsflash module and i create a custom layout called blocks.php

```
<div class="newsflash-block<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?> mod-list">
<?php for ($i = 0, $n = count($list); $i < $n; $i ++) : ?>
    <?php $item = $list[$i]; ?>
    <div class="tile col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <?php require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_articles_news', '_block-item'); ?>

        <?php if ($n > 1 && (($i < $n - 1) || $params->get('showLastSeparator'))) : ?>
            <span class="article-separator">&#160;</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Also i create a child layout called _block-item.php for displaying article elements

```
<div class="block-item">
<a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">

    <figure class="newsflash-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $item->imageSrc; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->imageAlt; ?>">

    <?php if ($params->get('show_introtext', 1)) : ?>
        <span class="text"><?php echo $item->introtext; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span class="title"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span>
    </figure>

</a>
```

The problem is in html-css side because i cant get the title or the text display over the image and not below. I am pretty sure i don't use the elements the right way.

I want my blocks look like this:
[image]

instead of this:
[image]

So the introimage of the article should be the background for the specific tile and in the div i should have the intro text and the title.

Comment: What CSS did you try? You should be able to wrap the 1-2 spans into a <figcaption> and position that one absolute. You need to be more specific with your question and code.

Comment: I made some changes in the code and ti seems it is working. I change the figure to div, span changed to divs that are childs to the upper div. So with some css (position: absolute, left and z-index values) and it seems ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to child layout called _block-item.php.

```
<div class="block-item">
<a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">

    <div class="newsflash-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $item->imageSrc; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->imageAlt; ?>">

        <div class="newsflash-data">
        <?php if ($params->get('show_introtext', 1)) : ?>
            <span class="text"><?php echo $item->introtext; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($params->get('item_title')) : ?>
            <span class="title"><?php echo $item->title; ?> ></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Changes to css

```
.block-item .newsflash-image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.block-item .newsflash-data .text{
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.block-item .newsflash-data .title{
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.newsflash-block .tile {
    padding-bottom: 135px;
}
.tile .block-item {
    padding: 5px;
}
.newsflash-image img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

The only ugly solution is the

```
.newsflash-block .tile {
padding-bottom: 135px;
```

}

so the block tiles don't stack upon each other. Anyone has a better solution;
[image]